# SourceTree not showing remote branches of a coworker

Tags: git, sourcetree

SourceTree not showing remote branches of a coworker.
We have three people in a project. I am trying to merge a branch of my coworker, but the branch is showing on github.com, but not on SourceTree.

https://github.com/liuduan/CAT-APP-PROJECT/network

[image: Sourcetree]

Comment: Which branch are you talking about? sumit... or mayukh...? If so, these are not branches in your repository, but the branch master in their forks of your repository. So if you want to see that commits, you have to configure their forks as remotes in your local repositories.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I switched between "All Branches" and "Current Branch" a few times, other people's branch showed up. It is not obvious at all. I spent a long time to figure it out.

Comment: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/47459/please-make-sourcetree-automatically-refresh-the-remote-status-on-opening-a-repo
“SourceTree refreshes the remote status (via 'git fetch', or 'hg incoming') only as frequently as specified in Preferences ('Check default remotes for updates ever X minutes),”
“If you want SourceTree to refresh faster you can reduce this time period, or use the 'Refresh Remote Status' option to trigger the process earlier.”

Comment: I made it refresh each minute, when I need it to refresh fast, and switch it back to each 10 minutes after I finish.

Answer (score 4):

Performing a `pruned fetch` will update all the `Remote` branches section with their state on `origin`. 
On Sourcetree, Click `Fetch` on the toolbar & ensure to select the options as in the image below.

[image: Voila]

Comment: Worked for me. I only checked "Fetch from all remotes" and left the other options unchecked.

Answer (score 3):

For me, after I removed the remote and add add it again in sourcetree, all remote branches showed up.

Answer (score 0):

I switched between "All Branches" and "Current Branch" a few times, other people's branch showed up.